# Remove public web access to Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an existing on-premises web app that I'd like to migrate to Azure, just a basic migration to start with.

The current app is made up of two websites, a publicly facing front end web site and a private SOAP API site that is accessibly only via a VPN connection.

I can happily place the front end in a standard web app, but can't see a cheap way of hosting the SOAP API. I have used Azure Service Environments in the past, but this approach is expensive and a bit much for the early stages of this migration.

Ideally I would just host the SOAP API in an Azure Web Site and put a Gateway infront of it to manage VPN access. But I'm struggling to see if that is supported.

Is there anything else I can do here?

Answer (score 0):

On the App Service hosting the API, have you looked into using the "Networking" blade to configure an IP restriction?  This way you could limit access from only the IP address of your front-end.

Additional considerations:

- There is no guarantee on a static IP for your front-end so you may need to consider range(s) based on what's in the DC you're app is hosted in (the IP doesn't change often but understand it's allocated from a pool that MS maintains).  For this solution, you'd also need to include the IP of any client needing access for development/debug since it wouldn't use a VPN
- You could also use a VNet to isolate services on the network and have more control over the configuration.  Unfortunately you'd also need to deploy the app into an ASE which will add further costs.  As a bonus, this would allow you to use a VPN as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can create a P2S VPN from the web to Vnet, create another S2S or P2S VPN from on-premise to Vnet. And there can be an NSG associated to the Vnet, so you can manage the VPN access. I think the document [Integrate your app with an Azure Virtual Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet)
could give you an idea. Unfortunately, you'd also need to deploy a VPN.